# Complement of a context free language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, semi-decidability, decidability

Consider the context-free language of balanced parentheses of three kinds:

$$L = \{w \in \{ (, ), [,], \{, \} \}^∗ \mid \text{all parentheses in }w \text{ are properly balanced}\} $$
What will be the complement of L? Will it be semi-decidable, Decidable, Context-free, or REG?
I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: What family of languages does $L$ belong to? What are the closure properties of this family?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: @Nathaniel L consists of all balanced parenthesis over those 6 characters

Comment: I know how to read, I am just proposing questions you should ask yourself to help you find the direction to take.

Comment: L is decidable as we can easily make a Turing machine for it. Intuitively it feels that the complement of L should be semi-decidable. But I am not sure how to go about proving it

Comment: A complement of a decidable language is decidable. Its a well-known result that you should be familiar with (and its not hard to prove...)

Comment: [Dyck languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language#Generalizations),  including the generalised form with multiple bracket pairs, are [deterministic context-free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language), a class with stronger closure properties than unrestricted CFLs.